# How does Spark in Java filter the values in the list in dataset?

Tags: java, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have two class, one is NewsArticle: String id, String title, List contents, the other is ContentItem: String content, String subtype, String url.

I want to filter out the content whose subtype value is equal to "paragraph", and spliced into one long string. (don't need url)

here is the `NewsArticle Dataset` like:

```
 1, "TiTle", [{htt..., paragraph, rem...},{htt..., paragraph, rem...},{htt..., paragraph, rem...}]
```

which is `id, title, List<ContentItem>`

I took out the contents column, and each single row is one article, it like this:

`[{http..., others, con...},{http..., paragraph, rem...},{http..., paragraph, rem...}]`

which is `url, subtype, content`

and now I want to make each article(row) look like:

```
1, "Title", "this is content which subtype equals paragraph"
```

can anyone help me with java?

Comment: Can you explain a little, maybe by adding sample data, and expected and actual outcome?

Comment: here is the NewsArticle like: 1, "TiTle", [{htt..., paragraph, rem...},{htt..., paragraph, rem...},{htt..., paragraph, rem...}], which is id, title, and List<ContentItem>

Comment: and now I want to make each article look like: 1, "Title", "this is content which subtype equals paragraph"

Comment: You can explode the list and then apply filter

Comment: I try explode, but each {} in list become a single row, I can't combine them again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This would work:

```
df
     .withColumn("newContent", functions.explode(functions.col("items")))
     .filter("newContent.subtype=='paragraph'")
     .selectExpr("id", "title", "newContent.content as content")
     .show(false);
```

Input:

```
+---+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+-----+
|id |items                                                                                                   |title|
+---+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+-----+
|id |[[Content1, subtype1, someurl], [ContentOfParagraph, paragraph, someurl], [Content2, subtype2, someurl]]|Title|
+---+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+-----+
```

Output:

```
+---+-----+------------------+
|id |title|content           |
+---+-----+------------------+
|id |Title|ContentOfParagraph|
+---+-----+------------------+
```